# Change some field separators in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a input file
1.txt

```
joshwin_xc8@yahoo.com:1802752:2222:
ihearttofurkey@yahoo.com:1802756:111113
www.rothmany@mail.com:xxmyaduh:13@;:3A
```

and I want an output file:
out.txt

```
joshwin_xc8@yahoo.com||o||1802752||o||2222:
ihearttofurkey@yahoo.com||o||1802756||o||111113
www.rothmany@mail.com||o||xxmyaduh||o||13@;:3A
```

I want to replace the first two ':' in 1.txt with '||o||', but with the script I am using

```
awk -F: '{print $1,$2,$3}' OFS="||o||" 3.txt
```

But it is not giving the expected output.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @jww: You don't have to necessarily down vote all the answers for this

Comment: @Inian - Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448).

Comment: @jww: The problem is getting to much hypocritical on half-decent questions like this. If this question is something the community recommends as off-topic, then I think more than 80% of the questions asked under `bash`/`awk` tag should be clarified as off-topic. I would recommend evaluate the question based on its 1) research efforts 2) readability 3) being on-topic( w/o spamming or blunt impractical questions) and if its good on that aspect, I see no problems in answering it. And a reckless downvote insults the time people who want to help out after their own evaluation of the question

Comment: I'd definitely welcome if certain tags are all directed towards particular site instead of spread over multiple sites... but I fail to see how this question is not a programming question and off topic for SO..

Comment: This is not about programming? It perfectly fits in the topic of 'a specific programming problem' under the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) @jww

Comment: @Inian - You missed the last part. According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the question must satisfy *"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*. This is nothing more than a question on how to use a command. It is certainly not unique to software development. There are other sites available to ask how to run commands.

Comment: @jww: We cannot be the judge of how the OP is planning to use the solutions given for his software. If at all leave a suggestion to the OP to seek information on what part of his software this piece fits into. All I'm suggesting is don't discourage the people answering who've spent enough time here to understand what is valid and what not for the sake of betterment of the community

Comment: @Inian - It does not matter how OP plans to use it. The question is either on-topic or off-topic. Out of curiosity, why did you not close the question as one of the duplicates available? There are [lots of them available](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+awk+to+replace+a+string+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: @jww: This has nothing do with my rep, If you've not seen I'm most active on the `bash` tag closing off duplicates at the earliest. And FYI, all the questions you've linked are not related to this. Assuming you've understood this question, OP does _not_ want all the delimiters to be modified, only the first two. It is NOT a dup of any of the questions you've shared.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: @Inian , why you deleted your answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `sed` may also help you in same.

```
sed 's/:/||o||/;s/:/||o||/'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply substituting 1st occurrence of colon with `||o||` and then 2nd occurrence of colon now becomes 1st occurrence of colon now and substituting that colon with `||o||` as per OP's requirement.

Comment: @down voter, please mention the reason for down vote.

Comment: Doesn't scale nicely. For example, if you wanted to replace the first 7 occurrences, that would be: `sed 's/:/||o||/;s/:/||o||/;s/:/||o||/;s/:/||o||/;s/:/||o||/;s/:/||o||/;s/:/||o||/'  Input_file`. See @choroba's solution.

Comment: @jreisinger, this solution is only for OP's posted sample Input_file which OP posted. For additional conditions we may need to add more logic into it rather that writing this substitute condition 7 times.

Answer (score 4):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/:/||o||/ for $_, $_' 1.txt
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing it
- `s///` is similar to substitution you might know from sed
- `for` in postposition runs the previous command for every element in the following list
- `$_` keeps the line being processed

For higher numbers, you can use `for ($_) x N` where N is the number. For example, to substitute the first 7 occurrences:

```
perl -pe 's/:/||o||/ for ($_) x 7' 1.txt
```

Comment: OP asks for a bash solution, why using perl for such a simple task?

Comment: @Nihvel all the other answers use external programs?

Comment: I usually use `cut` and `grep` if possible, then reach to `sed`, and then to `perl`.  It's been created for such tasks, and I find especially this solution pleasing as it doesn't repeat the substitution twice.

Comment: good one.. for generic case, `perl -F'/:/,$_,3' -lane 'print join "||o||", @F'` where `3` is number of replacements needed + 1...

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution also, but I think the idea can apply to other languages: using the limit parameter of split:

```
perl -nE 'print join q(||o||), split q(:), $_, 3' file
```

(q quotes because I'm on Windows)

Comment: The question is tagged linux

Comment: @123 yes, and perl code is portable. Quoting in the console is different though, on Linux you need single quotes and Windows double, which means if you have quotes inside your code you have to change them as well. q(:) is the same as ':' or ":" without that issue.

Comment: @Eily Yes, I understand that, it's just that you have put `(q quotes because I'm on Windows)` which isn't relevant since the question is tagged linux. I mean it isn't a massive issue just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @123 oh OK, I just added the comment to explain why I didn't use the more common syntax :). I thought it would avoid a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if we need to replace first 2 occurrence of : use below code

Like this you can change as per your requirement suppose if you need to change for first 7 occurences change {1..2} to {1..7}.

Out put will be saved in orginal file. it wont display the output

```
 for i in {1..2}
> do
> sed -i "s/:/||o||/1" p.txt
> done
```